# Com o CSS é possível mudar o cursor mais de uma vez ao interagir com o elemento?

Tags: css, html5, css3, ux

Eu tenho um elemento que vai pode ser movido pela tela.

Então pensando na ux/ui eu queria poder dar dois *feedbacks* para o usuário. O primeiro caso ele coloque o mouse sobre o elemento, e o segundo caso ele segure e arraste o elemento. Repare que na imagem abaixo tem a "mãozinha" e depois a "mãozinha" fechada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui tem um exemplo básico.

**OBS:** Repare que eu usei cursor 2x. Pois o primeiro é o `fallback` do segundo. Por exemplo, se o FireFox não reconhece o `-webkit-grab` vai utilizar o `pointer`. Já para quando for arrastar no caso do FireFox a ideia seria ter como `fallback` do `pointer` o `w-resize`.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com CSS mesmo, `:active` não resolveria?

```js
$(function () {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

#draggable:active{
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```

Comment: É isso ai! []´s

Comment: No Firefox o `:active` não funciona.

Comment: @Sam é verdade, testei agora no FF e no active não funcionou. Mas me conteitei como o w-resize no hover mesmo